# "no such key the specified key does not exist" Cloudfront error on HTTP Origin (API) additional behavior?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

**Context**

I'm currently facing a weird problem from my cloudfront distribution.

It has two behaviors. Default behavior displays static content from a S3 Bucket.
Additional behavior (/api/) is an endpoint to a dedicated HTTP Origin which is the website backend.

Here is the CDK code.

```js
const distribution = new Distribution(this, `${this.constructPrefix}-cloudfront-${this.constructSuffix}`, {
            defaultBehavior: {
                origin: new S3Origin(bucket, {
                    originAccessIdentity: oai,
                }),
                functionAssociations: [
                    {
                        function: cloudfrontFunctionRewritePath,
                        eventType: FunctionEventType.VIEWER_REQUEST,
                    },
                ],
                viewerProtocolPolicy: ViewerProtocolPolicy.REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS,
                cachePolicy: frontCachePolicy,
            },
            additionalBehaviors: {
                "/api/*": {
                    origin: new HttpOrigin(`${buildConfig.ApiURL}`, {
                        httpsPort: 443,
                        protocolPolicy: OriginProtocolPolicy.HTTPS_ONLY,
                        customHeaders: {
                            "x-cloudfront-secret": `${cloudfrontSecret.secretValueFromJson("password")}`,
                        },
                    }),
                    cachePolicy: apiCachePolicy,
                    viewerProtocolPolicy: ViewerProtocolPolicy.REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS,
                    allowedMethods: AllowedMethods.ALLOW_ALL,
                    edgeLambdas: edgeLambdaAssociations,
                    
                },
            },
            logBucket: bucketLog,
            logFilePrefix: "cloudfront/",
            enabled: true,
            defaultRootObject: "index.html",
            domainNames: [domainName],
            certificate: secureCertificate,
            errorResponses: [
                {
                    httpStatus: 404,
                    responseHttpStatus: 200,
                    responsePagePath: "/index.html",
                    ttl: Duration.seconds(86400),
                },
            ],
            ...(buildConfig.AWSWebAclArn !== "NONE" ? { webAclId: buildConfig.AWSWebAclArn } : {}),
        });
```

**The Problem**

**Right now, one of my API endpoint (/api/endpoint) on my Cloudfront distribution randomly returns a "no such key the specified key does not exist" with HTTP status code 404.**

Every other API endpoint works well. What's weird is that the response has an header with "Server: AmazonS3".

It seems like Cloudfront tries to get "/api/endpoint" from its default behavior (bucket S3) instead of the additional one (/api/).

Please note that it seems to work most of the time. I can't quite understand why Cloudfront is behaving like that at times.

Please, do you have any idea ?